# JPA 2 (Hibernate) persistence context per conversation - closed connection

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jdbc, jboss

I'm trying to implement a entitymanager-per-conversation pattern on a stateful proprietary web framework with JBoss 4.3.0 and Hibernate 4.3.5. In short, the goal is:

- First HTTP request loads entity A with lazy-loading properties from the database
- In second request, the lazy-loading properties of entity A are accessible without e.g. creating a new EntityManager and calling e.g. entityManager.merge(entityA).

Entitymanager-per-conversation seems like the perfect choice. Here's my attempt:

```
public class EntityManagerHolder {
    private static ThreadLocal<EntityManager> entityManager = new ThreadLocal<EntityManager>();        
    private static EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myPersistence");
    private static ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = new MyConnectionProvider();

    public static synchronized EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        createEntityManagerIfNeeded();
        return entityManager.get();
    }

    public static synchronized void createEntityManagerIfNeeded() {
        if (entityManager.get() == null) {
            // Start the conversation
            EntityManager newEntityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
            entityManager.set(newEntityManager);
            newEntityManager.getTransaction().begin();
        } else {
            // Entitymanager is alive but may have lost its connection
            EntityManager existingEntityManager = entityManager.get();
            SessionImpl session = existingEntityManager.unwrap(SessionImpl.class);

            try {
                if (session.connection() == null || session.connection().isClosed()) {
                    session.reconnect(connectionProvider.getConnection());
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Persistence.xml:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="myEntityManagerFactory">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <!-- Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files from this JAR -->
      <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
      <!-- Database connection settings: Use framework connections for database connectivity -->
      <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="foo.bar.MyConnectionProvider"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When a new HTTP request arrives via the framework, I call EntityManagerHolder.createEntityManagerIfNeeded(). On the second HTTP request, the JDBC connection of the EntityManager has closed and the attempt to revive it via session.reconnect() leads to an exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: cannot manually reconnect unless Connection was originally supplied

org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.manualReconnect(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:296)
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.reconnect(SessionImpl.java:478)
```

I realize I'm probably doing things in a very backwards way, but it would be nice to understand how entitymanager-per-conversation should be implemented. I've found the filter-based [Hibernate-specific sample implementation](http://jpwh.org/examples/jpwh/caveatemptor-native-061211/src/java/auction/web/filter/HibernateSessionConversationFilter.java) of this pattern, but haven't managed to bend it to my needs yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out [JBoss was closing the connections](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/WhatDoesTheMessageDoYourOwnHousekeepingMean). Disabling JBoss from closing JDBC connections would have resolved the issue. However, we wanted to avoid keeping a large number of JDBC connections open for long periods of time.

Best solution found so far is to revive the JDBC connection of the EntityManager, provided that the old connection is closed. I wrote a rough implementation:

[EntityManagerFactoryAdapter](http://pastebin.com/nwrGmnZR) - Used to reconnect an EntityManager to a new JDBC connection

[EntityManagerHolder](http://pastebin.com/t2p4a1j7) - Keeps one EntityManager per thread.

At the start of each HTTP request, we invoke EntityManagerHolder.initializeEntityManager(freshJDBCConnectionFromFramework). When the state is removed from the server, we invoke EntityManagerHolder.closeEntityManager(). Persistence.xml no longer has the hibernate.connection.provider_class - we're passing in connections manually.

I'm posting this just in case someone encounters a similar issue. This solution is very unorthodox, I'm hoping to replace it with a better one later.